# Open Graph: How to Give Star Rating to Something Besides Books or Movies

Tags: facebook-opengraph

How can I give a star rating to say, a place? AFAIK Open Graph currently only supports books and movies. When I try to create a custom "Rate" type FB tells me to use the "common rate" type which again, apparently only works for books and movies.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are out of luck. I dont think you can create a "rate" action for other types.
Also I tried using the `books.rates` and `video.rates` for rating a place, no luck!

One way this can be done, which might sound like a hack, is to create another action - something that resembles 'rating action' but have some other information that can be passed to it, which makes it different from rate action. Pulling this off might not be that easy considering Facebook's strict review policy. I will be trying to find a name for this kind of action and will update the answer accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck? I tried creating other actions like "review" but could not get it to function like `books.rates` and `video.rates` where a 1-5 star rating is included.

Comment: I take it you created a custom `review` action. If that is the case, it wont show 1-5 rating, because that is internally created by facebook on `rates`. Also did you submit the action to Facebook Review?